# Prometheus relabeling on Digitalocean

Tags: prometheus

I want to set the value of the label instance as hostname where it runs the Redis server.
But I have got an instance name where Prometheus runs.
Could someone prompt me on what I did wrong?

```yaml
- job_name: redis
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scrape_interval: 60s
    scrape_timeout: 15s
    digitalocean_sd_configs:
      - bearer_token: "{{do_key}}"
        port: 9121
        refresh_interval: 360s
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_droplet_name]
        target_label: instance
        replacement: $1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included examples of the labels **before** relabeling and **after**

Comment: I'm unsure of your intent with `[__address__]` --> `__param_target`. `__param_target` represents an internal label representing the Querystring `target`'s property. So this should be read-only and it will be dropped after relabelling anyway

Comment: The default `regex` is everything (`.*`) and the default replacement is everything (`$1`) so using `replacement: $1` is redundant but the behavior will be to map `__meta_digitalocena_droplet_name` to `instance` but that probably isn't a `host:port` value representing a (Redis) server?

Answer (score 1):

Thank everyone for the help and prompt me.
Finally, the configuration looks like this.

```yaml
  - job_name: redis
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scrape_interval: 60s
    scrape_timeout: 15s
    digitalocean_sd_configs:
      - bearer_token: "{{do_key}}"
        port: 9121
        refresh_interval: 60s
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_tags]
        regex: .*,monitoring_yes,.*
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_droplet_name]
        target_label: instance
        replacement: $1
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_public_ipv4]
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: '$1:9121'
```